# Is it possible to preview watson assistant bot without sample webpage ( just the chatbot)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Currently, to preview your watson assistant chatbot on IBM, a preview link is given. However, it shows the bot on a sample webpage and the bot on the bottom right corner. It used to show the chatbot on a direct URL. Is it possible to revert the web URL to reflect this?

[sample web with watson assistant in corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8grR.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqHS9.png): [preview link given by IBM watson assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqHS9.png)

Comment: Are you using the classic or the new Watson Assistant experience? What exactly is the problem? Is the preview not working and you cannot test?

Comment: Hi, I am using the classic version and the legacy preview link where the bot appears full screen on a URL was my goal. But now that the legacy preview link is depreciated and the preview link has a sample website with the bot in the corner. Is there a way for me to revert these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Watson Assistant Web chat provides a snippet in the Embed tab.
Take the snippet, just put it in a `html` file and open that file from your browser, you will get just the chat

[image: Web chat embed tab]

Alternatively, if you can use a blank screen website such as or just http://www.blankwebsite.com/, and you can add it here:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but the HTML file appears quite localized. I am trying to have the bot appear on a URL website and hopefully the bot will appear fullscreen, instead of the corner pop up (even with the blank website). Basically, having a sharable preview link that is like the legacy version.

Comment: change the snippet to open by default https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-configuration#optionsopenChatByDefault